# Problems on poker game and comparator?

Tags: java, comparator, poker

I am trying to create a poker game in which I create the deck in the Card class, and use a comparator to sort the deck in alphabetical order. I'm having trouble with what to put in the comparator, and in my dealer class, (this is where I create the deck, shuffle, as well as calling the comparator). When my CompareCards does compile, my Dealer class will give me the error of:

```
    Dealer.java:24: error: incompatible types: void cannot be converted to String
    String s = Collections.sort(deck);
                               ^
 Note: Dealer.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
 Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

I know that when doing the sort, you have to include the Comparator name, but in this case it doesn't work either way. Here is my card class:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Card{
    String suit = null;
    String value = null;
    String rank = null;

    public static final String[] SUIT = {"C", "D", "H", "S" };

    public static final String[] RANK = {"A","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","T","J","Q","K"};

    public Card(int i, int j){
        suit = RANK [i];
        rank = SUIT [j];
        value = rank + suit;
    }
    public String getSuit(){
        return suit;
    }

    public String getRank(){
        return rank;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return(value);
    }
}
```

Here is my Comparator and CompareCards class:

```
public interface Comparator <Card>{
    public int compare(Card o1, Card o2);
}

public class CompareCards implements Comparator<Card>{
    public int compare(Card c1, Card c2){
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        int dx = c1.getRank() - c2.getRank();
        if(dx == 0){
            x = c1.getRank()-c2.getRank();
        }
        else{
            y = c1.getSuit() - c2.getSuit();
        }
        return x;
    }
```

And here is the dealer class:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Dealer{

public static void main(String[]args){
    // creating deck
    List<Card> deck= new ArrayList<Card>();

    // calling Card
    for(int i = 0; i < 13  ; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 4 ; j++){
            // String s = RANK[i] +SUIT[j];
            deck.add(new Card(i, j));
        }
    }
    finding21(deck);
}

public static void finding21 (List deck){

    String s = Collections.sort(deck);
    System.out.println("Sorted deck: " + s);
    // After I sort the deck I am supposed to do a binary search
    // for the queen of hearts
     /* Collections.shuffle(deck);
          System.out.println("Shuffled deck: " + deck);
          String HQ =  Collections.binarySearch(deck, "HQ");
          System.out.print(HQ);

          System.out.println(queenH);*/
    }
}
```

Comment: Card class: great idea. Member variables for suit and rank: great idea. Making them strings: terrible idea. Strings are for humans, computers use numbers. Make the member variables simple integers, and just convert to strings for display. It will make everything else you have to do 1000x easier.

Answer (score 4):

[`Collections.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)) does an in-place sort and does not return a value.

That's why the compiler says you can't convert a `void` to a `String`.

The `void` type is used for functions with no return value.

Just use:

```
Collections.sort(deck);
```

If you want to print the sorted `deck` after, you can use:

```
System.out.println("Sorted deck: " + deck);
```

Comment: So how would I change this?